# Two different ways of putting the script at the bottom - what are the differences?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous-javascript

What are the differences between the two solutions below ?
In particular, is there a good reason to favour 2 over 1. (note: Please assume the name of the script to load is known. The question is just about if there is value in creating a minimal script to load a script in the given situation )

**1 - Script At The Bottom**

```
<html>
<body>
...
...
<script src='myScript.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2 - Script at the bottom loads external script**

```
<html>
<body>
...
...
<script>
    // minimal script to load another script
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'myScript.js'
    document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Mahdi I check that question. I don't see why the two questions are related...

Comment: @Mahdi there's no problem with appending. Read more carefully, please.

Comment: @Zo72 They are explaining what are the effects and difference between each ways. Isn't that what you were looking for, before the edit actually?

Comment: @Dropout I didn't say there is a problem with appending. If you read the other question, you will see why I was flagging that as duplicated. Also please consider that the original post is edited -- which is fine and clears the air, however I did flag it before the edit.

Comment: @Mahdi can you remove the link to the unrelated question please ?

Comment: @Zo72 Shouldn't this be the accepted answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/22957114/1491212

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Script at the bottom**

When you use a "synchronous" script tag, it will **block** the browser from rendering the page until the script is loaded and executed. This method has the following effects:

- Regardless of where you put the script tag, the browser cannot fire [**DOMContentLoaded**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) until the script is downloaded and executed.
- Placing such a script tag at the bottom only ensures that the browsers has rendered all content before getting blocked by the script.

**2. Script at the bottom loads external script**

When you inject a script tag using JavaScript, it will create an "asynchronous" script tag that does not block the browser. This method has the following effects:

- Regardless of where you put the JavaScript code that generates the script tag, the browser executes it as soon as it is available without blocking the page. The DOMContentLoaded fires when it should; irrespective of whether the script has downloaded/executed.

The second approach has the following advantages:

- The script that injects a script tag can be placed anywhere including document head.
- The script will not block the rendering.
- DOMContentLoaded event does not wait for the script.

The second approach has the following disadvantages:

- You cannot use `document.write` in such scripts. If you do, such statements might wipe the document clean.
- Asynchronous execution does not mean that browser has finished parsing the page. Keep the *script executes as soon as it is available* clause in mind.
- Execution order is not guaranteed. Example: If you load "library.js" and "use-library.js" using injected script tags, it is possible for "use-library.js" to load and execute before "library.js".

---

Having said all that, there is another method for loading scripts, with three variations:

```
<script src="myScript.js" async></script>
<script src="myScript.js" defer></script>
<script src="myScript.js" async defer></script>
```

---

Regarding Steve Souders's work: he proposed 6 techniques for [loading scripts without blocking](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/). The `async` and `defer` attributes introduced in HTML5 cover the **Script DOM Element** and **Script Defer** techniques and their browser support is more than enough for you to worry about the other techniques.

Comment: **That** is a valuable bounty hunter answer!

Answer (score 11):

One important feature of the second one is that it allows the browser to finish parsing the page immediately, without waiting for the script to load. That's because the first example allows the script to use `document.write` to change the parsing state around the `<script>` tag, while the second one doesn't.

Now, we know that it's at the bottom of the page so that there isn't any important *content* left to parse, but this is still an important difference. It's not until parsing is done that the browser fires the popular `DOMContentLoaded` event. In method 1, the event fires after the script loads and executes. In method 2, the event fires before the script starts loading.

Here are some examples. In these demos, a `DOMContentLoaded` listener changes the background color to yellow. We try to load a script that takes 3 seconds to load.

1. http://jsfiddle.net/35ccs/
2. http://jsfiddle.net/VtwUV/

(edit: Maybe jsfiddle wasn't the best place to host these demos. It doesn't show the result until the slow-loading script loads. Be sure to click Run again once it loads, to see what happens.)

Pick the approach that's best for your application. If you know you need the script to run before `DOMContentLoaded`, go with method 1. Otherwise, method 2 is pretty good in most cases.

Comment: this is valuable feedback. if DOMContentLoaded is the only concern you probably will deserve to get the bounty...

Comment: I think you're right on this one ... adding a `<script src=...` tag will block the page, but using `appendChild` will not block.  It might actually be **preferable** to block the page in many cases, such as loading jQuery before your own code.

Comment: How is this the accepted answer without even mentioning defer / async ?

Answer (score 3):

These two ways of initializing a script are basically the same, although theres no reason to use the second way if you can directly put in the result. However you can wrap the second example in a `$(document).ready()` method for example which would lead to sort of a lazy loading effect. This basically means that the page would load first and after the loading of the page is finished it would load the script. Or of course you can create a method which initializes a certain script this way. It's useful when you have a large script which is used only in some situations. This would prevent loading it unless you need it, thus decreasing the overall loading time.

Comment: you are probably right when you say: "although theres no reason to use the second way if you can directly put in the result"... but do you know for sure ?

Comment: @Zo72 I am probably sure ;) Check the results in your browser's console (networking and source tabs, don't use CTRL+U).

Comment: @Dropout I'd +1 but there is no enough content

Comment: @rowly is an example of such initialization method enough content? I would be glad to provide more info, but it's kind of a broad topic.

Comment: there is no jQuery on the example

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it's good to know regardless.

The 2nd approach is sometimes used as a **library fallback**.
For example, you load jQuery from the Google CDN.  But, if it were to fail for any reason, load jQuery from your own local copy.

Here's how the popular HTML5 Boilerplate recommends doing this:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method means that the script tag is hardcoded in. The second method dynamically adds a script tag to the bottom of the page using JavaScript. The benefit of the second method is that you can add additional logic if needed to modify the script tag. Perhaps you might want to load a different script file based on culture, browser or some other factor you can determine in JavaScript. The second method also causes the JavaScript file to be loaded without blocking the loading of the rest of the web page. In method one the page will stop loading when it gets to the script tag, load the JavaScript file, then finish loading the rest of the page. Since this tag is at the bottom of your page it doesn't make too much of a difference.

If you are creating a Windows Store app using JavaScript then the first method is recommended as this will allow the app to bytecode cache the JavaScript file which will make it load up faster.